# Copying from Various Tabs and Pasting into Main Sheet (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code to copy everything from various tabs in cells `A:H` (starting in row 3) and paste everything on the main tab starting in cell `B5` and moving down?

My current code is:

```
Sub CopyToMainsheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Main" Then
            ws.Activate
            Range("A3:H3").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
            Sheets("Main").Select
            Range("b" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The issue with this code is that it doesn't go back to `B5` if you do it more than once and keeps pasting below what has already been pasted. I need it to start pasting in `B5` every time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just clear your output sheet at the start of the code?

Comment: Avoid using `Select`. And make the `Worksheet` the `Range`s are on explicit. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @SJR Because it should be in a table format... if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. If there's stuff in Main you want to preserve, that bit will need tweaking.

```
Sub CopyToMainsheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, r1 As Long

r = 5
With Worksheets("Main")
    r1 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If r1 > 4 Then .Range("B5", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 8).ClearContents
End With

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Main" Then
        ws.Range("A3", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 8).Copy
        Sheets("Main").Range("B" & r).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                   Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        r = Sheets("Main").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @sjr I really like this one! Pardon my ignorance but how would I have to edit the above if I wanted to only delete the contents in the range B:5 to H:100000? Thanks again

Comment: And have the resulting pasted values formatted as a table for filtering?

Comment: Code amended above, to just delete everything in Main from B5 down.

Comment: This works really well but also deletes the contents in row 4...?

Comment: Have added a check which should rectify that.